# Arrays.compareTo for byte[] arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a reason why [java.util.Arrays class](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) does not support a compareTo function for different array types, specifically byte[] arrays? I have found a sample implementation [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cassandra/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteComparisons.java), but I'm mostly wondering if I'm overlooking some common Java class.

EDIT: compareTo does not behave like Arrays.equals but more so like [String.compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Expectedly it does not provide any compareTo() method, since it does not implement the Comparable interface. For a class with only static methods like Arrays it does not make sense in my opinion.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? I don't see what the semantic purpose of the proposed `compareTo` is when applied to an array.

Comment: @arjacsoh obviously it would be `static int compareTo(byte[] a, byte[] b)`

Comment: @chrylis e.g. in order to define a total order on a set of arrays, e.g. in order to put them (or objects containing them) in collections that require such an order

Answer (score 3):

Following is a generic `compare()` function for arrays in Java. You can modify for your needs in case you have a different interpretation for what makes one array "greater than" another in non-straightforward scenarios (different lengths, nulls, etc.). It can also be changed easily to work on primitives, such as `byte`, `int`, etc.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int compareArray(T[] a, T[] b) {
    if (a == b) { // also covers the case of two null arrays. those are considered 'equal'
        return 0;
    }

    // arbitrary: non-null array is considered 'greater than' null array
    if (a == null) {
        return -1; // "a < b"
    } else if (b == null) {
        return 1; // "a > b"
    }

    // now the item-by-item comparison - the loop runs as long as items in both arrays are equal
    int last = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
        T ai = a[i];
        T bi = b[i];

        if (ai == null && bi == null) {
            continue; // two null items are assumed 'equal'
        } else if (ai == null) { // arbitrary: non-null item is considered 'greater than' null item
            return -1; // "a < b"
        } else if (bi == null) {
            return 1; // "a > b"
        }

        int comp = ai.compareTo(bi);
        if (comp != 0) {
            return comp;
        }
    }

    // shorter array whose items are all equal to the first items of a longer array is considered 'less than'
    if (a.length < b.length) {
        return -1; // "a < b"
    } else if (a.length > b.length) {
        return 1; // "a > b"
    }

    // i.e. (a.length == b.length)
    return 0; // "a = b", same length, all items equal
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No specific reason, other than code bloating, which always has played a major role in java: the Java installation always been called a large overhead. A compareTo on `byte[]` would be signed wouldn't it? Would you like an unsigned too? How often would it be used? Maybe nothing for the core Java.

But you have a point: equals could have been implemented using compareTo.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of compareTo on an array depends on your use case. Thus it is not implemented in java.util.Arrays and because not every array contains comparable objects..

If you want to implement a `compareTo` Method on an array you have to answer the question:

> When is one array less than, equal to or greater than another array?

If the array is a `byte[]` that is based on an ascii string it might be easy, but then you have a special use case.

Take a look at these questions to understand what I mean:

1. How would you compare an array of `Comparable`s when you don't know much more about the elements than that they are `Comparable`s?
2. What kind of information do you get if you know that one array of `Comparable`s is less than another array of `Comparable`s because each element at the same index is less than the other array's element at the same index and what would you do with such information?
3. What would be the information that you will get if you compare the binary representation of 2 executable files?

I think that the `byte[]` is a very specific use case, becuse you think of the `byte[]` as a string of ascii characters, but remember that the `byte[]` representation of a string depends of the encoding.

Comment: You don't have to think of a `byte[]` as a string of ascii characters in order to compare them. It's just an array of numbers.